# Чем является MySQL для SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Я не могу понять чем является MySQL для SQL? Или это одно и то же, но синонимы?

Comment: SQL - это язык работы с данными. Этим языком пользуются в различных СУБД (системах управления базами данных). Причем по факту не смотря на наличие неких стандартов на этот язык у каждой СУБД по факту свой диалект.и возможности. А MySql - это одна конкретная из десятков СУБД работающих с этим языком

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*SQL* - язык реляционных баз данных, *MySQL* - система управления базами данных (СУБД), которая при помощи команд на языке *SQL* осуществляет различные операции с БД.

Также есть СУБД *PostgreSQL*, *Microsoft SQL Server*, *Oracle* и др. Все они используют язык *SQL*, расширяя его собственными дополнительными синтаксическими плюшками, образуя т.н. диалект языка *SQL*.

Comment: _T-SQL_-это разве СУБД? Это расширение языка _SQL_

Comment: Вы правы. Имел ввиду реализацию от Microsoft